# Twitter idioms: Why do some Japanese have an "@" in the middle of their "names" (not usernames)?

Tags: idioms, internet-slang

I've noticed that some Japanese Twitter users put words/short sentences separated by an "@" symbol in the "name" field. A common one I've noticed is "abc123@LINEスタンプ販売中," which seems to imply they're selling stamps on LINE. Some even have multiple "@" symbols in between stuff.

It seems to be fairly common in the Japanese Twitterverse, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: You know, that's an interesting question. My impression is that the stuff after the @ is used kind of like status messages were used in the older days of instant messengers (IRC, AIM, etc.).

Comment: @senshin That's what I suspected as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember seeing @ being used to indicate current status, what they're doing, etc since over 10 years ago.

And I remember using it myself.

Like:

[My name here]@管理人

to indicate that I was the webmaster.

Oh the good old internet...

The usage seems to have survived those years.